# Python code for setting storage class and location of a bucket using

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I can create a bucket in a specific location and of a specific storage class using gsutil command as follows.

```
gsutil mb -c regional -l asia gs://unique_bucket_name
```

I am trying to find an appropriate api in google client library in python. So far, I could manage to create a bucket using following code but could not specify the location or storage class type.

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'my-unique-bucket'
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Any help/suggestion on setting up the location and storage class of the bucket is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I had to use as I don't think it is possible to directly pass in this information to the `create_bucket` method.

```
api_response = storage_client.connection.api_request(
                   method='POST', 
                   path='/b', 
                   query_params={'project': 'YourProjectName'}, 
                   data={'name': 'my-unique-bucket', 
                         'location': 'asia', 
                         'storageClass': 'regional'})
```